# Question on Linear Algebra (related to Affine Combination)

Tags: linear-algebra

The book I am using mentions this theorem:

$$A\subseteq V\text{ is a flat} \iff A\text{ is closed under affine combinations, that is}\\ x_1,\ldots,x_k\in A,\ \ \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_k,\in F,\ \ \alpha_1+\cdots+\ \alpha_k=1\Rightarrow\ \alpha_1x_1+\cdots+\alpha_kx_k\in A$$

The following question within the exercise then refers to this theorem (specifically the RHS of the above iff statement):

> Let $ 1+1\neq0$ in $F$.
>
> Show that closure under affine combinations for $k=2$ implies closure under affine combinations for all $k\geq1$.

---

My approach so far has been to use Strong Induction.

Assuming the result holds for $k\leq n$,  we show it holds for $k=n+1$

consider $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_ix_i  $

choose $l\in\{1,2,\ldots, k+1\}$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_ix_i=\beta\sum_{i=1}^{l}\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta}x_i+\gamma\sum_{i={l+1}}^{k+1}\frac{\alpha_i}{\gamma}x_i$

(Note: $\beta = \sum_{i=1}^{l}\alpha_i \neq0$ and $\gamma = \sum_{i=l+1}^{k+1}\alpha_i \neq0$)

Using induction hypothesis, $\sum_{i=1}^{l}\frac{\alpha_i}{\beta}x_i\in A$ and $\sum_{i={l+1}}^{k+1}\frac{\alpha_i}{\gamma}x_i\in A$. Call them $x$  and $y$ respectively.}

Now, $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_ix_i = \beta x+ \gamma y$

Since the result holds for $k=2$, $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1}\alpha_ix_i\in A\
  $

---

My question is twofold. First, I never made use of the fact that $1+1\neq0$ in F. What am I missing here? Second, how can I show that the condition in line 3 of my solution (when I introduce l and break the summation into two sums) can be assumed without loss of generality?

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption about the characteristic of $F$ comes into play when we justify the claim you ask about, so the questions are one in the same.  Here's a start...

Firstly note that you can assume all the $\alpha_i$ are nonzero.
Then start by dividing the sum into $\beta' = \alpha_n$ and $\gamma' = \sum_{i<n} \alpha_i$.  We split the problem into cases.

Case (1) $\gamma' \not = 0$ and there is nothing to prove.

Case (2) $\gamma' = 0$ and $\alpha_j \not= -\alpha_n$ for some $j <n$.  Then we modify the division as $\beta = \alpha_n + a_j$ and $\gamma = \sum_{i \not= j,n}\alpha_i$ and are done.

Case (3) $\gamma' = 0$ and $\alpha_j = -\alpha_n$ for all $j <n$.  By assumption, $2\alpha_j \not= 0$.  Hence, if we set $$\gamma = \gamma' + 2\alpha_n = \sum_{j< n-2} \alpha_j$$ $$\beta = \beta' - 2\alpha_n = \sum_{i\geq n-2} \alpha_i = -\alpha_n$$ then $\beta, \gamma \not= 0$

Comment: If $\gamma = 0$, then $\beta = \alpha_n = 1$. Going to case (3) that you've mentioned, it would imply that $\gamma = 0=-\alpha_n-\alpha_n-\cdots \ -\alpha_n=-1-1-\cdots - 1$. Now how would I proceed from this point and use $1+1\neq 0$?

Comment: i edited a better explanation for case (3), hope that helps